# Вывод на экран и в файл при подключении по SSH

Tags: python-3.x, print

При выполнении следующего скрипта я вывожу на экран и файл по средству двух принтов:

```
import paramiko
import time


switch = 'any.switch'
user = 'admin'
secret = 'pass'


ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname=switch, username=user, password=secret, port=22)

print ("\n\n####NewInvoke Shell####\n")

chan = ssh.invoke_shell()
output = chan.recv(9999)
print (output.decode('utf-8'))
print (output.decode('utf-8'), file=open('logfile.log', 'a'))


print (chan.send_ready())
chan.send('terminal length 0\n')
time.sleep(2)
output = chan.recv(9999)
print (output.decode('utf-8'))
print (output.decode('utf-8'), file=open('logfile.log', 'a'))


chan.send('sh ver\n')
time.sleep(2)
output = chan.recv(9999)
print (output.decode('utf-8'))
print (output.decode('utf-8'), file=open('logfile.log', 'a'))


chan.send('sh ver | i time\n')
time.sleep(2)
output = chan.recv(9999)
print (output.decode('utf-8'))
print (output.decode('utf-8'), file=open('logfile.log', 'a'))
print ("\n\n###End invoke Shell###\n\n\n")

input('\nPress Enter for quit')
```

Как ещё можно решить данную задачу? Возможно ли её решить в одну строчку?

Comment: Задача состоит в выводе на экран?

Comment: Да, в выводе на экран и записать вывод в файл.

Comment: Посмотрите мой ответ, там код сокращён.

Comment: Отредактировал, возможно стало ближе к тому, что Вам было нужно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я верно понял автора, сократить объём кода можно так:

```py
import paramiko
import time

def LogInfo(Chan):
    output = Chan.recv(9999)
    print (output.decode('utf-8'))
    print (output.decode('utf-8'), file=open('logfile.log', 'a'))

switch = 'any.switch'
user = 'admin'
secret = 'pass'

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname=switch, username=user, password=secret, port=22)

print ("\n\n####NewInvoke Shell####\n")

chan = ssh.invoke_shell()
LogInfo(chan)

print (chan.send_ready())
chan.send('terminal length 0\n')
time.sleep(2)
LogInfo(chan)

chan.send('sh ver\n')
time.sleep(2)
LogInfo(chan)

chan.send('sh ver | i time\n')
time.sleep(2)
LogInfo(chan)
print ("\n\n###End invoke Shell###\n\n\n")

input('\nPress Enter for quit')
```

Чтобы вывести в разные места (консоль и файл) "одновременно", одной строки явно недостаточно. Но общий метод примерно такой:

```py
import sys
files = (sys.stdout, open("file.txt", "w"))

for f in files:
    print("hello", file=f)
```

Этот код выведет `hello` в файл и в консоль. А при добавлении в кортеж `files` других расположений, и в них тоже.